# Why should the tension be constant throughout if there is external force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, string

I came across a question from *Pathfinder for Olympiad*. The question was:

*A frictionless non-conducting inextensible thread of length l wears three beads of positive charges q1 , q2 and q3. The ends of the thread are connected to make a knotless loop. Length of the thread is so large as compared to the size of the beads that the beads can be treated as point particles. The system is in a state of equilibrium with beads at vertices of a triangle.*

*Find lengths l1, l2, and l3 of the sides of the triangle.*

In this the condition they used is that tension is same throughout the string(In all the three sections the tension has the same magnitude). But what I don't understand is how is the tension constant throughout the string if at some point the bead also applies force. Then a small part of the string at a corner should have forces due to the bead as well as the tension from two sides of the string. Hence why should the tension be equal?

Comment: Try drawing a free-body diagram of the section of thread (with or without a bead) you claim to  feature different tension magnitudes at the ends. Then apply the equations of equilibrium, incorporating the fact that the bead must pull perpendicular to the thread, or it will start to slide. Can the tensions be different?

Comment: A couple things weren't immediately clear to me. The beads can slide without friction along the thread. The beads slide until they are in equilibrium. And the charges aren't necessarily equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the question isn't why tension within one straight section is constant. It is why is the tension the same in all three straight sections.

The beads slide without friction. Think of them as 3 frictionless pulleys in an Atwood machine. The tension is the same in all straight sections because a frictionless pulley exerts no force along the thread. It is the same here.

Comment: If it was not mentioned that the string was frictionless then we cannot consider the tension to be the same in all sections right?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If tension is not constant, this would lead to tangential force on the string leading to "slithering". Take a small rope element between the position $s$ and $s+ds$ ($s$ being the coordinate describing the position on the rope, this is a Lagranian description), let $\vec t$ and $T$ be the respective tangent vector and $T$ the tension. The tension force is therefore:
$$
\begin{align}
d\vec F &= T(s+ds)\vec t(s+ds)-T(s)\vec t(s) \\
&= \left(T\frac{d\vec t}{ds}+\vec t\frac{dT}{ds}\right)ds \\
&= \left(T k\vec n+\frac{dT}{ds}\vec t\right)ds \\
\end{align}
$$

with $\vec n$ the normal vector and $k$ the curvature (used Frenet's equation). This confirms that variations in tension lead to tangential accelerations (there is no other force compensating it). It would contradict the equilibrium assumption.

This is treated in more details for example in Mark Levi's *Why Cats Land on their Feet*.

Hope this helps.